# Installation of Safari on a RPI 3 model B

Tags: software-installation

I am a diehard mac user and have recently bought an RPI 3 model B. Because I am so used to Safari I was curious if it is possible to install Safari on a pi, and if so how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. Safari requires an `x86` processor to run, and the Raspberry Pi has an `ARM` processor. For more information on why this is problematic, we have a helpful [blog post](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/140986024839/installing-applications-on-a-raspberry-pi-running).

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely keep this in mind for other applications!

Comment: can't we build from sources , but I think Safari is not open source

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz it is closed source.

Comment: I really like safari's bookmarks management . I usually research the web from my MacBook and sometime use the same bookmarks from my iPhone . This makes life lot easier

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Yes, Yes it does :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Epiphany via `sudo apt install epiphany`. This is the official WebKit browser for Linux https://webkit.org/downloads/. So it uses the same rendering and JavaScript engine as Safari. It just has a different appearance and lacks all the convenience features.
It also was the first browser officially supported by the Raspberry Pi foundation back in the days.

BUT
It has no advantage over Chrome any more.
I don't know how actively the version in the repo is maintainend.
You have to assume that Chrome will be more up-to-date in this regard.